# div problems at 100% width and 100% height

Tags: html, css, flash, scrollbars

I'm having this problem for over a year, and still didn't find the answer.  So thank you in advance for helping me out!

I have a SWF embedded in HTML (it is placed in a div) and putted width and height at 100% (to make the flash file cover the whole screen). This works fine!  But if you resize your browser the flash file gets (obviously) too small to read anything.

Is it possible to stop scaling the content when it is smaller than, for example, 200px, and replace it with scrollbars?

Thanks in advance!
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your CSS:

```
min-width: 200px;
```

And if you need to limit the height of an element:

```
min-height: 200px;
```

Comment: Don’t forget `overflow:auto` to add scrollbars for the overflowing content.

Comment: @TomDeWitte you're welcome :) when you ask a question in SO and you get an answer which solves your problem you should give set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this.....

html

```
<div id="container">

  /* content */

</div>
```

css

```
#container {
        width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
#container {
        width: 200px;
}

}
```